# is it possible in angular to set the debug log level at runtime?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to switch the `$logProvider.debugEnabled([flag]);` at runtime?

The current situation:

The angular client load settings from the server at the run phase. Depends on the settings I would like to set the method `$logProvider.debugEnabled([flag])`.

Thanks in advance, Stevo

Answer (score 1):

The short answer for this is: no, not really.

Once your application hass been configured through your `.config()` block, no further configuration can take place after the application has bootstrapped.

This is due to the way providers work; they're only available at configuration time. There might be a way to force the configuration, and then manually re-inject the new `$log` service into all of your controllers, but if there is a way to do that, I'm not sure how.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the app config. I basically put the setting in a JavaScript file so I have all the settings at the start up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I've decorated `$log.debug(...)` to change the loglevel at runtime.

Looking at [Enhancing AngularJS Logging using Decorators](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/10/07/enhance-angularjs-logging-using-decorators/), I got the idea for the following code snippet:

```
(function () {
    var KEY = "debugEnabled";

    angular.module("service.config", [])
        .config(function ($provide, $logProvider) {
            // AngularJS has debug enabled by default, but just to be sure...
            $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);

            // Disabling localStorageDebug (if not set)
            if (localStorage.getItem(KEY) === null) {
                localStorage.setItem(KEY, "false");
            }

            // add a check for localStorageDebug before actually calling $log.debug(...)
            $provide.decorator('$log', function ($delegate) {
                var debugFunction = $delegate.debug;

                $delegate.debug = function () {
                    if (localStorage.getItem(KEY) !== "false") {
                        debugFunction.apply(undefined, arguments)
                    }
                };

                return $delegate;
            });
        })
        .service("ConfigService", function ($log) {
            this.debugEnabled = function (flag) {
                $log.info("Setting debugEnabled to " + flag);
                localStorage.setItem(KEY, flag.toString());
            }
        });
})();

// exposing ConfigService to global scope (be aware of possible clashes!),
// therefore making it easily accessible from the console
var cfg;
window.onload = function () {
    cfg = angular.element(document.body).injector().get("ConfigService");
};
```

The decorator only forwards calls to `$log.debug` if `debugEnabled` is set to `true` in your local storage - the value can be changed through the `ConfigService` service.

Now you can just call `ConfigService#debugEnabled` with the value you've loaded from your server to change the loglevel.

Thanks to the last four lines, you can also simply call `cfg.debugEnabled(true)` on your console to enable debug mode at runtime.

If you don't like to type into the console, you could avoid the global `cfg` and use javascript bookmarks (or elements on your website) to change the log level.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was by

1. manually injecting $cookies into the config block, then
2. using that as a reference within a service.
3. referring to the service var in all read locations.

   ```
   'use strict';
   app
     .config(['$logProvider', function($logProvider ){
       var $cookies;
       angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(['$cookies', function(_$cookies_) {
         $cookies = _$cookies_;
       }]);
       var _enabled = $cookies.debugMode;
       $logProvider.debugEnabled(_enabled);
     }])
     .factory('DebugSvc', ['$cookies', 'HttpMonitorSvc',function ($cookies, HttpMonitorSvc) {
     return  {
       httpMonitor: HttpMonitorSvc,
       debugMode: $cookies.debugMode || 'inactive',
       setDebugMode: function (mode) {
         var _logEnabled = $cookies.debugMode;

         switch( mode ) {
           case 'active':
             _logEnabled = true;
             break;
         }
         $cookies.debugMode = mode;
         this.debugMode = mode;
       }
     };
   }]);
   ```