# AngularFire - How to set logging level?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire, but I don't see any way to set the logging level for debugging purposes.  The [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore#set-log-level) shows you can, but AngularFire doesn't seem to give you access to this object.

How can I set the logging level using AngularFire?  If there is no way to do it, how would you suggest I do it using the general firestore SDK in Angular?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there isn't a specific way to import it, however, after some research, I could find this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/190#issuecomment-371180738), that provides you an option of importing, that might help you.

You can give it a try using this following code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');
```

This way, you can try to set logging level.

Besides that, these other two below posts from the Community, you can find more information and options on logging error for debugging with Angular. I believe they might help you as a starting point.

- [is it possible in angular to set the debug log level at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322242/is-it-possible-in-angular-to-set-the-debug-log-level-at-runtime)
- [How to log errors with Firebase Hosting for a deployed Angular web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212886/how-to-log-errors-with-firebase-hosting-for-a-deployed-angular-web-app)

These other two articles provide more information on the use of Firestore with Angular.

- [How the AngularFire Library makes Firebase feel like Magic](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-the-angular-fire-library-makes-firebase-feel-like-magic-1fda375966bb)
- [Using Cloud Firestore in Angular With AngularFire](https://alligator.io/angular/cloud-firestore-angularfire/)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Link-only answers are considered, very low quality. Please consider adding some meaningful context into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, the import syntax got updated since user13068860's answer. I got the following to work in AngularFire `6.1.5`.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');
```